# Creating a set from Table Valued Function in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, wcf-data-services

I have a database with very big tables(some of them may have more than 1,000,000 records) and every user of this database should see some of this data, so we have multiple TVF(Table valued function) that get a user ID and select those records of the table that is visible to that user(this operation require multiple `SELECT` statements and I think calling TVF is far better than implementing it in the code).
In first release of the program to my clients, I had a class with multiple properties of type `IQueryable` that implemented using LinqToSql and it worked great.
Now I have a client that want to use my assembly to write a WCF data service, so I have to write a class derived from `DbContext`(using EF) that can be used in specified service.
My problem is:

- `DbContext` automatically expose all `DbSet` properties that defined in it, so every user with minimum level of access can see entire data of the table(of course client app will restrict data, but client can access data directly and even import those data to an Excel or Access using OData)
- I have multiple public properties of type `IQueryable` but they will not appeared in the list of data that exposed by WCF data service.

In order to solve this problem, I think the most complete solution is to be able to call TVF as a table and create a set from it. But I don't know how to do this?!

**Note**
  Any change to the database require some logging, so I have stored procedures to do those changes, so I only require read only access to my WCF data service and I don't want default sets that contain all records of the tables published in the service

Comment: i am not sure, but I would think that you can just use a Select Statement the same that you would if you were going to Select from a Table to populate the dataset.

Comment: @Malachi thanks for your answer, but I can(and actually I already do) get an IQueryable from my TVF, but the problem is WCF data service only show all DbSet properties of my DbContext, I want to hide all that properties and show my IQueryable properties instead, but I don't know how!

Comment: Can you not create a service class that constrains access to your TVF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get the functionality you want by using a [customized data service provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg191846.aspx) to define the shape of your WCF service. That can get pretty complicated, but since you already have a bunch of IQueryables, you'll probably be able to use the [Reflection Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723653%28VS.100%29.aspx), about which the docs say:

> The reflection provider exposes data in classes that return types that implement the IQueryable interface. WCF Data Services uses reflection to infer a data model for these classes and can translate address-based queries against resources into language integrated query (LINQ)-based queries against the exposed IQueryable types.

That documentation links to a "How to" for using the Reflection Provider. Basically you just create a pseudo-context class with IQueryable properties, add a few attributes to your data objects, and point your DataService at your pseudo-context type. (If you're using Database/Model-first EF, you'll probably need to create partials of your entities in order to add the attributes, or update the T4 templates.)

Comment: So much thanks for your answer, I previously try to use ReflectionProvider and had some difficulties, but I will try by changing T4 templates. But do you know that if this technique support MetadataTypeAttribute or not?

Comment: @BigBoss, I'm pretty sure it does not; I just dotPeek'd inside ReflectionServiceProvider in System.Data.Services and it's not using any System.ComponentModel stuff, it's just looking for the `DataServiceKeyAttribute` on the data object types.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a recordset-returning parameterized stored procedure (SP) with the UserID as a parameter?  Entity Framework can work with this.

You could call your TVF in the SP, or just transliterate the TVF content in the SP.

If you needed add/delete/update functionality, you may need SPs for those functions too, if your query is non-updateable.

Comment: First thing is functions in SQL can't change database, but SPs can!! And second is I can't query data from SP and expect optimizer to optimize it for me(replacing TABLE with SP is not possible) but I can do this with TVF and that's the reason of TVF existance(I guess)

Answer (score 0):

**DbContext automatically expose all DbSet properties that defined in it**

*I suggest, You make the view in Database Or make use of Linq2Sql template.*

> 1. If you make the view, Model designer make proper DataTable.
> 2. If you use linq2sql template, 
>     You could make the data model which has only
>      properties you want to show others. 
>     
>      (After erasing connectioninfomation on linq2sql and allocing with connctionString, it is just
>      how to use.)

**I have multiple public properties of type IQueryable but they will not appeared in the list of data that exposed by WCF data service.**

*Make the model and Using linq and method ExcuteJsonAll.* 
If someone recieve JSON file, someone make it available.

> **How to make the model to stored procedure.**
>
> 1. Make Select SP In Database.
> 2. Update Your model from Database
>
>    Here, You Bring the SP.
> 3. In edmx Or model view, You Make the function using SP.
> 4. During Creating the function, You Could make the DataSet related return value of sp.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but VIEWs won't work because I have many users(and users can create new users) so I can't create a new view for each one of them, and if I can how should I use them with EF??

Comment: Maybe, The problem is Returning IQueryable<Model>. Model's property is open to User. You should make select procedure. And... From select sp, you make the model.

Comment: Just returning IQueryable, do not solve the problem, I'm already able to return an IQueryable from a TVF and this have a better performance from SP. But the problem is all sets will be published with data service and user can download them and also a property of type IQueryable won't published by DataService, so user can't download them using normal tools of OData and only can access to that data programmatically. So we have invalid data published and correct data hidden!